# Angular routing question - 2 doughnut holes

Tags: javascript, angular

I am reviewing a template project in angular

The bootstrap component has an HTML template that looks like this. Makes perfect sense. App-header, app-sidebar etc are tags that will have content supplied by components w/ matching selectors. This all checks out.

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>


    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div class="task-overlay" data-reff="#task_window"></div>
    <div class="sidebar-overlay" data-reff="#sidebar"></div>


</div>
```

The Sidebar is predictably a menu and there are routes that look like this (just an excerpt..)

```
{ path: 'events', component: EventsmainComponent },
  { path: 'chat', component: ChatsComponent },
  { path: 'activities', component: ActivitiesComponent },
  { path: 'inbox', component: EmailmainComponent },
```

These components have a selector that is not found in any HTML template  in the entire project (app-email). I believe angular is 'saying'

"*When the url is \inbox, i am  going to grab the EmailMainComponent and insert that in the ROUTER-OUTLET placeholder tag*"

Here is where my understanding stops.

**1. I don't see  Router-Outlet mentioned in the routing? Is Router-Outlet a reserved tag?**

**2. What if my layout was split screen and i wanted half the menu options to refresh the top half, with the remaining menu items refreshing the bottom half.
How do I tell those links in the latter group that the target should be Router-Outlet2?**

Comment: Sounds like you want to use **named router-outlets**. Here is a [link](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/) that will explain it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) of angular router:

> The **RouterOutlet** is a directive from the router library that is used like a component. It acts as a placeholder that marks the spot in the template where the router should display the components for that outlet.

You can add multiple router outlet tags using a name as follow:

```
<!-- This is the placeholder for component of the first part of the screen -->
<router-outlet name="first">   

...
<!-- This is the placeholder for component of the second part of the screen -->
<router-outlet name="second">
```

and referencing them in the routes configurations as follow:

```
...
{path: '/yourPath', component: YourComponent, outlet: 'first'},
{path: '/yourPath', component: OtherComponent, outlet: 'second'}
...
```

So if you go to the url `/yourPath` you will see `YourComponent` in the first box and `OtherComponent` in the second box